# server not understand post value from multiple form in 1 page

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a page with 3 form only in 1 page.

```html
<body>
    <!-- form 1 -->
    <form action="" method="post" id="form_1">
      ...
      <button id="submit_update" name="submit_update" type="submit"  value="submit">update</button>
    </form>

    <!-- form 2 -->
    <form action="" method="get" id="form_2">
      ...
      <button id="submit_search" name="submit_search" type="submit"  value="search">search</button>
    </form>

    <!-- form 3 Need submit this form -->
    <form action="" method="post" id="form_3">
      ...
      <button id="submit_update_2" name="submit_update_2" type="submit"  value="submit">Finish Update</button>
    </form>
    </body>
```

All above form no action specific and submit to this php page. On localhost(PHP/5.5.12), it's ok, but on hosting(PHP/5.6.18), it not success when I click button Final Submit I use statement var_dump($_POST)->no value, with statement var_dump($_REQUEST) -> only session appear.
I used jquery to trigger third form. but it not success.
Maybe, there is some config in php.ini or this page on hosting just understand submit event from first form and second form (form 1 and form 2 is ok), just form 3 not working. I don't want use only 1 form for all, because it's different business.
I checked cookie on localhost, it have : session and PHPSESSID, and hosting just has session, no anything else. is it important to affect post result.

I additional jquery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#form_3 #submit_update").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#form_1").submit(false);
  $("#form_2").submit(false);
  $("#form_3").submit();
  
 });
});
```

Comment: Show more code, what jquery you are using. Why so many forms with same actions on the same page?

Comment: because that is the business and I follow design, same action because I require_one all file in index file and I don't want redirect from another page.